# Firebase custom Token with CustomUserClaims

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm can currently succesfully use Firebase admin node sdk to `createCustomToken`.  I know I can pass the token back to the client and using `signInWithCustomToken` sign in a user and het the `UID`. However, I am using custom authentication is the first place is because I'm creating `sub-users` with limited permissions that `adminUser` allows. I was hoping to use `setCustomUserClaims` to attach some data to the sub-users so I can show the correct sub-user ui and set correct security rules in database. However I can't seem to figure out how I can set the `customClaims` beacuse I don't have the `sub-user` `UID` until I call `signInWithCustomToken` on the client. What is the process to do this correctly?

Code I was hoping to run right after creating a `customToken` for a `subUser`

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {subUser: true, viewPermisson: true}).then(() => {
});
```

Comment: You can set custom claims just after creating or updating users (you have uid) , I think this is not a operation you need to do after every custom token generation. So you may not associate createCustomToken with the setCustomUserClaims operation.

Comment: if I use `admin.auth().createUser({})` then that just create a anonymous user , with what creds will subUser login after I use this function?

Comment: It creates a anonymous user because I'm not using email or phonenumber. I don't have UID

Comment: I am not sure but there may be a property to check if user is anonymous or not in realtime database rules :/